# How to remove NullPointerException while using array as an object of the class?

Tags: nullpointerexception

I have declared an array type object of a class and i am getting a string input from a user. I am then splitting that string into its tokens and trying to store those tokens in that array type object of the class but it always throws the Nullpointerexception. I thing this is because i haven't initialized the data fields of the array so they were automatically assigned null value by the constructor call.`

```
Employeee[] emp=new Employeee[4];
System.out.println("Enter data:");
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
   String s=input.nextLine();
   String tok[]=s.split(",");
   emp[i].id=Integer.parseInt(tok[0]);
     what should i do to get rid of this exception?
```

Comment: the array declaration does not reserve memory for the elements. You need to create an employee instance and assign it to an array element before you can access its members.

Comment: You also need to make sure your input is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

`emp[i] = new Employee();` .  And say what language you're using in the tags.